# Cannot access file I exposed with Android FileProvider via another application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I am trying to expose a file using file provider and then read this file in another application I developed.

Here is the code for the app that exposes the file and triggers the intent:

```
val intent = Intent(ACTION_INSTALL)
            intent.setPackage(servicePackage)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_URI, 
            "content://com.mma.apkprovider/apks//storage/emulated/0/main_app-release.apk")

            // Launch the installer service
            context.startForegroundService(intent)
```

Along with the following AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<permission
        android:name="com.mma.permissions.APK_PROVIDER"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application>
        <provider
        android:name=".ApkProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mma.mainapp.ApkProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:permission="com.mma.permissions.APK_PROVIDER" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/apk_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Here is the code for the app that gets triggered from the intent  should read the file:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    log("onStartCommand called...")
    log("action: ${intent?.action}")
    log("flags: $flags")
    log("action: $startId")
    val action = intent?.action
    val uri = intent?.getStringExtra(EXTRA_URI) ?: return START_NOT_STICKY
    if (action == ACTION_INSTALL) {
        log("Install APK $uri...")
        executor.submit {
            performInstallation(Uri.parse(uri))
        }
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

private fun performInstallation(uri: Uri) {
    try {
        val packageInstaller = packageManager.packageInstaller
        val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL
            )
        )
        val session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)
        val uniqueName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        //
        val file = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
        val size = file?.statSize ?: throw IOException("Couldn't read file from provider!")
        file.close()
        val outputStream = session.openWrite(uniqueName, 0, size)
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            ?: throw IOException("Couldn't read file from provider!")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_RESULT).also { it.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, e.message) }
        sendBroadcast(intent)
        loge("Error installing $uri", e)
    }
    //...
}
```

Here is the stack trace I get from the installer app:

```
D Installer: onStartCommand called...
10-19 16:27:57.310  3814  3814 D Installer: action: com.mma.INSTALL
10-19 16:27:57.310  3814  3814 D Installer: flags: 0
10-19 16:27:57.310  3814  3814 D Installer: action: 3
10-19 16:27:57.324  3814  3814 D Installer: Install APK content://com.mma.main_app.ApkProvider/apks//storage/emulated/0/main_app-release.apk...
10-19 16:27:57.332  2607  2607 W Binder:2607_8: type=1400 audit(0.0:45866): avc: denied { dac_read_search } for capability=2 scontext=u:r:installd:s0 tcontext=u:r:installd:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
10-19 16:27:57.576  3814  7880 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.mma.main_app.ApkProvider
10-19 16:27:57.336  2607  2607 I chatty  : uid=0(root) Binder:2607_2 identical 3 lines
10-19 16:27:57.336  2607  2607 W Binder:2607_8: type=1400 audit(0.0:45870): avc: denied { dac_read_search } for capability=2 scontext=u:r:installd:s0 tcontext=u:r:installd:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer: Error installing content://com.mma.main_app.ApkProvider/apks//storage/emulated/0/main_app-release.apk
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: content://com.mma.main_app.ApkProvider/apks//storage/emulated/0/main_app-release.apk
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1445)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1296)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1149)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1103)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at com.mma.installer.InstallerService.performInstallation(InstallerService.kt:74)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at com.mma.installer.InstallerService.access$performInstallation(InstallerService.kt:18)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at com.mma.installer.InstallerService$onStartCommand$1.run(InstallerService.kt:46)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
10-19 16:27:57.588  3814  7880 E Installer:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

So I am having issue finding the content provider from the installer app.
I am stuck for days on this. I am new to the use of providers/content resolvers, this looks quite complex to me.

**EDIT**

ApkProvider is a FileProvider subclass:

```
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider

class ApkProvider : FileProvider() {}
```

Comment: `content://com.mma.apkprovider/apks//storage/emulated/0/main_app-release.apk` You are not using the FileProvider to construct an uri. Moreover the one you made is completely impossible.

Comment: `android:name=".ApkProvider"` You are not using FileProvider.

Comment: `Intent(action)` Which action?

Comment: `context.startForegroundService(intent)` ? What has that to do with exposing a file? And we dont know what you do. Difficult helping if all is vague.

Comment: In addition to all the problems pointed out by blackapps, your authorities do not match. Your unfortunately-hardcoded `Uri` uses `com.mma.apkprovider`, but your `android:authorities` is `com.mma.mainapp.ApkProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I edited the post to clarify:
- ApkProvider is a FileProvider subclass
- action is a string that is the same on both application ; the action is triggered correctly so this is not the issue

To clarify, the final goal is to install an APK using a privileged app (the installer app).
The main app stores an APK in the filesystem (/storage/emulated/0/main_app-release.apk). Then it triggers the privileged app through an intent. The installer app receives the intent (working) and should then read the APK on the filesystem, using ContentResolver.

Comment: From my understanding, to expose a file between two apps, one app must expose it using FileProvider (a specific ContentProvider) and the other one must read it using ContentResolver.

Comment: It makes no sense to use ApkProvider class as it extends or adds nothing. Better use FileProvider directly. Further you are still building that impossible uri instead of using FileProvider.getUriForFile().

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the FileProvider/ContentResolver/Uri APIs which are quite error prone and does not provide clear warning/error messages.

The file to be shared can simply be saved into */data/local/tmp ("${Environment.getDataDirectory()}/local/tmp")*
And retrieved from the other activity without specific permissions.

The triggered app can simply read the file from absolute path:

```
val file = File(apkPath)
val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
```